# MassTransit 3 with AzureServiceBus prefixing a slash to queue names

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to run my application in Azure using MassTransit 3

> The entity name or path cannot contain '/' as prefix or suffix. The
>   supplied value is '/profile.api'. Parameter name: entityName

The only way I can see the prefix being added to the queue name is via MassTransit.

Oddly enough, the queue has been created in my Azure Portal under the name "profile.api".

Has anyone else experienced this before? I'm not sure if this is a bug with MassTransit or if I have missed a step in my configuration.

The full stacktrace is below.

Thanks.

> [ArgumentException: The entity name or path cannot contain '/' as
>   prefix or suffix. The supplied value is '/profile.api'. Parameter
>   name: entityName]
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +381 
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.EndCreateMessageReceiver(IAsyncResult
>   result) +70
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization) +86
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Pipeline.-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
>   +794    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26    MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Pipeline.-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
>   +2756    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Pipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +1599    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.<b__0>d.MoveNext() +531
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   MassTransit.Internals.Extensions.d__0`1.MoveNext()
>   +924    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    MassTransit.<StartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +1154
>
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
>
>   MassTransit.<StartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +2025
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    MassTransit.Util.TaskUtil.Await(Func`1 taskFactory,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) +222
>   MassTransit.MassTransitBus.MassTransit.IBusControl.Start() +61
>   SampleApp.Startup.ConfigureBus() +33
>   SampleApp.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +428

Comment: This might be a bug when you're using the namespace uri without any suffix. I usually add the service name at the end of the uri. That way the queues are "scoped" to the service making them easier to find in service bus explorer.

Comment: Issue added, and closed: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a very subtle difference in how my application was configured compared with how the MassTransit tests run their azure configuration.

Whereas I had **(does not work)**

```
public class AzureBusModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
            {
                var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("sb://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureEndPoint"]), h =>
                {
                    h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureKeyName"],
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureKeyValue"]);
                });

                sbc.UseSerilog();
                sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
                //sbc.UseRetry(Retry.Exponential(10.Seconds(), 3.Minutes(), 10.Seconds()));

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"], ep =>
                {
                    ep.LoadFrom(context);
                });

            });

            Log.Information("Finished Configuring MassTransit using Azure");

            return busControl;
        })
        .SingleInstance()
        .As<IBusControl>()
        .As<IBus>();
    }
}
```

Changing the following **fixed my issue.**

```
var serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb",
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureEndpoint"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureEndpointName"]);

var host = sbc.Host(serviceUri, h =>
{
    // [...]
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: I would like to point out that the original implementation you had is as the MassTransit documentation suggests http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/master/configuration/transports/azure.html However as you have said, the MassTransit Tests implement the serviceUri using a ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri method to produce a working Uri to pass into the host. This will also prefix any queue created with the specified AzureEndpointName. In our example, this leads to a queue called "profile_host/input_queue" rather than the expected "profile_host" we were originally expecting.